# D7 - Can't set selected value of a webform select element

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm trying to set the selected value of a webform select form element before it is rendered. I'm using the below code and the textfields are working just fine but no luck with the select options.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_webform_form(&$vars) {
    $vars['form']['submitted']['emailAddress']['#value'] = 'some@email.com'; //This is working
    $vars['form']['submitted']['country']['#selected'] = 'BARBADOS'; // This is not working even though #default value is used instead
}
```

I can't figure it out why this is not working for select field. I would be glad if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value by using #value

```
$vars['form']['submitted']['country']['#value'] = 'BARBADOS';
```

But make sure that the select option key should be same

**Example:**

```
<option value="BARBADOS">BARBADOS</option>
$vars['form']['submitted']['country']['#value'] = 'BARBADOS'; //will work

<option value="barbados">BARBADOS</option>
$vars['form']['submitted']['country']['#value'] = 'BARBADOS'; //will not work
$vars['form']['submitted']['country']['#value'] = 'barbados'; //will work
```

Comment: Thanks man, I've spent hours for this, didn't expect it would be that easy.

Comment: Always welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For webform forms, I think you have to set #value to TRUE on the option itself.

Something like this should work:

```
$vars['form']['submitted']['country']['BARBADOS']['#value'] = TRUE;
```

If there are any other default values, you'll have to set those to FALSE.

Comment: Thanks a lot but nope, didn't work either